# How do I pass dynamic header values to a Micronaut declarative HTTP client?

Tags: micronaut

I would like to take advantage of the 'Declarative HTTP Client' feature of Micronaut. I am having a difficult time understand how to pass in a dynamic header value and was wondering if this is even possible. Consider the following example:

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Header;
import io.micronaut.http.client.annotation.Client;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Client("${my.api.host}")
@Header(name = "Auth-Header", value = "<This needs to be dynamic>")
public interface MyApiClient {
    public ArrayList<Dog> getDogs();
}
```

How can I make my header value dynamic [non-static]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dynamic headers in declarative client can be defined on the method argument level. See the example below:

```java
@Client("${my.api.host}")
interface LocalhostClient {
    @Get
    List<String> getDogs(@Header(name = "Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

Then you can call the client method with appropriate *Authorization* header value like this:

```java
var dogs = client.getDogs("Bearer some-token");
```

Comment: `List<String> getDogs(@Header(name = "Authorization") String authorization);` - In that particular example I think `name="Authorization"` is optional.  By default the name will be whatever the parameter name is, which in this case is `authorization`.  A common use case for specifying the name is when the header name needs to include a hyphen, for example `public String someMethodName(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType)`.

Comment: Jeff's comment is correct, and I think that's a bug actually. This tripped me up. When the `Header` annotation is used this way, the `name =`  annotation parameter is ignored and the name of the method parameter is used instead. This can be a problem. For example, my param name was "auth" and so Micronaut was creating a header named literally "auth" when what I needed was "Authorization". This took me a couple hours to debug! I'm using Micronaut 3.0.3

Comment: Update. Basically, `name = ` and `value =` do not work the same way on a class-level annotation vs a method param-level annotation and this is actually documented in the code comments on the Header class. Read it carefully: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/3.2.x/http/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/annotation/Header.java#L60