Micronaut multiple headers
How to pass multiple number of different headers in Micronaut Declarative client, using Map<String,String>, with [name:value] syntax?
@Header annotation requires fixed name, so It should be defined only once.
@Headers also provides only multiple number of single @Header.
For example a client should call with different headers every time, how to solve it?
EDIT
Thanks for answers, I have seen post How do I pass dynamic header values to a Micronaut declarative HTTP client?
I have used it already, but it offers to add a dynamic value in Header (pass different value each time when call declarative client).
But I want to pass different headers (each with different name and value), so, not to write them all static.
If it is possible of course

Do you have an example of what you've tried and why it didn't work?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321394/6509

This question is similar to: How do I pass dynamic header values to a Micronaut declarative HTTP client?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
